# Need the background image slideshow to show only on One Parallax page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a Parallax website which has  in one full index.html page. For example, home page is 1 div, aboutus page is 1 div, products page is 1 div etc.

When I run the website, it shows the background img slideshow in all the divs. I want the background slideshow to appear in HOME page div only.

How can I do that?

I had put an image into ONE div called home, but still when I run the page, the whole website has that background slideshow.

My code is:

```
<div id="headerwrap" name="home">
    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
         <li><span>Image 01</span>
            <div><h3></h3></div></li>
         <li><span>Image 02</span>
            <div><h3></h3></div></li>
         <li><span>Image 03</span>
           <div><h3></h3></div></li>
         <li><span>Image 04</span>
           <div><h3></h3></div></li>
         <li><span>Image 05</span>
           <div><h3></h3></div></li>
         <li><span>Image 06</span>
           <div><h3></h3></div></li>
     </ul>
 <header class="clearfix"> 
<div id="homepagelogo"> </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a question

Comment: I have added your code to the question. You should use the [edit] button to clarify the question and add more information and not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The slideshow its showing in all the pages probably because it has a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that you are missing closing tag `</div>` of your home div somewhere. That can cause that everything after home div belongs to that div and therefore everything has its background. check that.

note: to prevent theese mistakes, you should follow code formating and use validate tools like w3 validator:
https://validator.w3.org/